# Jruby + Testunit + Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, jruby, testunit

I'm working with Jruby 1.6.8 and Rails 3.1 doing tests with TestUnit and Capybara and after doing some tests, I started seeing "Errors running test:single!
". It happened to me sometime but after launching tests again it was fixed.

I'm launching this command:

```
jruby --debug -S rake test TEST=path_to_my_test
```

and even trying with: `rake test TEST=path_to_my_test` I can't fix it.

Here you have my log:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/jmolina/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/native/i386-Linux/libjffi-1.0.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Errors running test:single!
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I realized my test database was dropped (I don't know why). So I recreate it again, and now it works fine.